# How to avoid nested promises with multiple Mongoose operations?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, nested

I'm sorry I know there are already some posts treating the nesting promises problems in NodeJS, but I still can't figure this one.
I'm using Express and Mongoose and I want to find an Object ID, then save an Object, and then update another Object but I don't understand how should I do better than this since these are dependant promises :

```
        // Get Client object ID from email
        Client.findOne({ email: req.body.clientEmail })
          .exec()
          .then((client) => {
            // Then add Client ID to program and save
            const program = new Program(req.body);
            program.Client = client._id;
            program.save()
              // Finally add the program to the existing coach user
              .then((program) => {
                Coach.updateOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, { $push: { programs: program._id } },
                  function (err, coachUpdated) {
                    if (err) return handleError(err);
                    console.log(coachUpdated);
                  })
              })
              .then(() => { res.send('New program added!'); });
          })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid nested promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318627/how-to-avoid-nested-promises)

Comment: Instead of nesting a `.then` in another `.then`, `return` the second Promise, and consume it in the next *outer* `.then`

Comment: learn about async and await

Comment: try to use async/await instead of Promises, it will help you get your data correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Along with async/await. use try/catch block.**

```
async function findClientAndUpdateCoach(req, res) {
    try {
        const client = await Client.findOne({ email: req.body.clientEmail }).exec();

        const program = new Program(req.body);
        program.client = client._id;
        const result = await program.save() // Must be asynchronous in nature to prevent blocking..

        Coach.updateOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, { $push: { programs: program._id } },
            function (err, coachUpdated) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                console.log(coachUpdated);
                res.send('New program added!');
            });
    }
    catch (err) {
        return handleError(err);
    }

    findClientAndUpdateCoach(req, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `async/await` I would do something like

```
const client = await Client.findOne({ email: req.body.clientEmail })
          .exec();
const program = new Program(req.body);
program.Client = client._id;
const {_id} = await program.save();
//If this is not a promise. you can still use `promisify` from `utils` standard node.js lib to make it a promise
// and then call it with await. :) 
Coach.updateOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, { $push: { programs: _id } },
    function (err, coachUpdated) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(coachUpdated);
})
//You can choose to place it inside the callback above.
res.send('New program added!');
```

Note: The outer wrapping function should be prefixed with `async` like `async function (req, res) {...`